# javascript not working on button as expected

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to connect previous and fwd buttons to a gallery and I want the previous button to be hidden on first image of the gallery but javascript doesn't seem to be working at all.

### Javascript

```
var imageGallery = new Array();
imageGallery[0] = '1.png';
imageGallery[1] = '2.png';
imageGallery[2] = '3.png';
imageGallery[3] = '4.png';
imageGallery[4] = '5.png';
var imgCount = 0;
function next() {
    imgCount++ ;
    document.getElementById("gallery").src = imageGallery[imgCount] ;
}

function previous() {
    imgCount--;
    document.getElementById("gallery").src = imageGallery[imgCount] ;   
    }
```

```js
if(document.getElementById("gallery").getAttribute("src") == "1.png")
    {
    document.getElementById("previous").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
else 
    {
    document.getElementById("previous").style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
```

### HTML

```
<div id="img">
<img id="gallery" src="1.png" style="height:420px; width:744px" >
<div id="imgNav">
    <a id="previous" href onclick="previous(); return false;">previous</a>
    <span style="color:#666; font-size:0.9em"> | </Span>
 <a id="next" href onclick="next(); return false;">next</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Actually the logic is if 'src' attribute of id 'gallery' is '1.png' then 'visibility' of element with id 'previous' is 'hidden' else not but doesn't seem to be working. Can anyone help figuring it out.

Comment: What error are you getting on the console?

Comment: nothing...it just isn't hiding as expected at the very first image of the gallery..

Comment: Where are your previous() and next() functions?

Comment: "javascript doesn't seem to be working at all" is a VERY broad statement.  Have you put in `alert`s or `console.log` or `debugger` statements to see if javascript is working?  Chances are it's working fine, and what you're seeing is that your code executes at a time you're not expecting.

Comment: Is the `href` attribute like hat in your code or have you just hidden it in this post? That may be a problem.

Comment: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/mBMF3/6/).

Comment: @Andy worked for me as well in fiddle...but not in editor i don't know...I really have no idea...let me try these suggested tweaks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably trying to check on an image that's not totally loaded yet. Did you remember to place your code to run just when the page is fully loaded (in case it's placed in the page headers - you didn't mention whether it is or not)?

**UPDATED**

```
var imageGallery = new Array();
imageGallery[0] = '1.png';
imageGallery[1] = '2.png';
imageGallery[2] = '3.png';
imageGallery[3] = '4.png';
imageGallery[4] = '5.png';

var imgCount = 0;

function checkNav() {
    var previousLnk = document.getElementById("previous");
    var nextLnk = document.getElementById("next");

    previousLnk.style.visibility = imgCount == 0 ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
    nextLnk.style.visibility = imgCount >= (imageGallery.length - 1) ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
}

function setImg() {
    var gallery = document.getElementById("gallery");

    gallery.src = imageGallery[imgCount];
}

function next() {
    imgCount++;
    setImg();
    checkNav();
}

function previous() {
    imgCount--;
    setImg();
    checkNav();
}

window.onload = function () {
    checkNav();
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/N7V9E/

Comment: It kind of has worked but only partially now it doesn't show previous button again when src attr is not 1.png. I mean it remains hidden...ans yeah the code is placed in the header.

Comment: This code is running just once. So you need to re-run it on the navigation (previous/next) clicks aswell.

Comment: I've updated the answer to make it more clear and easier to work (if you need to change something).

Comment: Found the problem images were called before they were being loaded...Thanks